# What is the easiest way to get liquidity pool information on Raydium or other DEXs?

Tags: liquiditypool

I want to receive information about the liquidity pool such as: market cap, liquidity, price

I have seen the official Raydium SDK, but I am not so strong in js similar languages

Maybe there is something simpler and suitable for Python?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get that information from dexscreener fairly easily with https://api.dexscreener.com/latest/dex/tokens/H5n9BQfULHEEtvLVf2WErUHsXHhRaUkYqVhNzxUkWJGf

so something like:

```
url = "https://api.dexscreener.com/latest/dex/tokens/H5n9BQfULHEEtvLVf2WErUHsXHhRaUkYqVhNzxUkWJGf"

resp = httpx.get(url)
data = resp.json()["pairs"]

   for token in data:
        
     contract_id = token["baseToken"]["address"] 
     symbol = token["baseToken"]["symbol"]
     liq = token["liquidity"]["usd"]
     fdv = token["fdv"]
     price = token["priceUsd"]
```

Comment: Yes, but if pool was set with postponed trading, dexscreener doesn't show any info until trading starts

Comment: The solution was to automatically calculate all the data based on what information I get about new pools